# Overflow-scrolling:touch breaks overflow:hidden on child elements in Mobile Safari

Tags: ios, css, ios7, mobile-safari

I am trying to draw a half circle and rotate it using CSS. Like so;

[image: Looks fine in all desktop browsers]

To style the div.circle I use border-radius:50%; then I wrap it in an overflow:hidden; div.mask that is half the width of the circle, thus hiding half of the circle. Then I use transform:rotate(45deg) to rotate the div.mask. This works fine in all browsers that I've tested.

```
<div class="mask">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>

.mask {
  outline: 1em solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.circle {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

But when I place this element in a block that has overflow-scrolling:touch; and overflow:scroll; and view it on Mobile Safari on iOS7 the half circle becomes a full circle because the overflow:hidden; on the div.mask doesn't seem to have an effect anymore.

```
.scroller {
  border: 1em solid green;
  overflow: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

[image: Looks broken on iOS7]

How do I fix this?

[Here's a live example](http://codepen.io/jessehattabaugh/pen/pDshI)